# ?how to make a two dimensional matrix

Tags: python

I have 1 dictionary and 1 tuple

```
 students = { 0: "Nynke", 1: "Lolle", 2: "Jikke", 3: "Popke", 4: "Teake", 5:
"Lieuwe", 6: "Tsjabbe", 7: "Klaske", 8: "Ypke", 9: "Lobke"}

friendships = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5,
6), (5, 7), (6, 8), (7, 8), (8, 9)]
```

First thing I have to make is a 2-dimensional matrix wherein for each student a list with their friends like:  [[1, 2], [0, 2, 3], ..., [8]]

the second thing is i have to sort the list based on the number of friends i have to print it like: [(9, 1), (0, 2), ..., (8, 3)]. 
number 9 has only 1 friend, number 0 has two friends etc...

my code:

```
for i in students:
    for x in friendships:
        if students[i] == friendships(x):
            new_list.append(x)
    print(i)
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do you mean that in your resulting 2-dimensional matrix, each inner list's first value is the number of a student and the remaining values are numbers of students who are direct friends of that student?

Comment: @RoryDaulton no, it says number 0 has 1 and 2 as friends, number 1 has number 0,2,3 as friends and go on...

Answer (score 0):

Not a 100% sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do, so correct me if I have the wrong idea. But here's what I think,

For the first one you can try creating a dictionary to store every friendships

```
all_friends = {}
for f in friendships:
   if f[0] in all_friends:
      all_friends[f[0]] = all_friends[f[0]] + [f[1]]
   else:
      all_friends[f[0]] = [f[1]]
```

Then you'll want to get a list of this dictionaries values, and that'll be your 2d matrix:

```
all_friends.values()
```

For the second one you will first need to keep track of how many friendships each person has, try a dictionary for this

```
friendships_dict = {}
for f in friendships:
   if f[0] in friendships_dict{}:
      friendships_dict[f[0]] = friendships_dict[f[0]] + 1
   else:
      friendships_dict[f[0]] = 1
```

Then you'll want to make that a list of tuples that you can sort:

```
friends_list = [(f1, f2) for f1, f2 in friendships_dict.iteritems()]

sorted_friends_list = sorted(friends_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

**EDIT**

Now that I better understand the first part of your question, let me go ahead and try to offer a solution.

You'll still want the first piece of code I included:

```
all_friends = {}
for f in friendships:
   if f[0] in all_friends:
      all_friends[f[0]] = all_friends[f[0]] + [f[1]]
   else:
      all_friends[f[0]] = [f[1]]
```

Then add the following:

```
matrix = [] 
for key in sorted(all_friends.iterkeys()):
    matrix.append(all_friends[key])
```

And `matrix` will be what you wanted

Comment: for the first one i want to create a list with  [[1, 2], [0, 2, 3], ..., [8]].  But I'm stuck. I think I use the wrong method

Comment: Can you explain what that list signifies?

Comment: it says number 0 has 1 and 2 as friends, number 1 has number 0,2,3 as friends.

Comment: it prints out: 0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

but what does iterkeys?